# Textured alpha not showing in the game engine?

Tags: rendering, texturing, game-engine, particles

No matter what texture setting I'm in, none of the particle objects will display materials or texture, instead, I just get squares.

[image]

I've been having a lot of texture issues lately and even tried resetting factory settings, but things like this still get messed up. Is there a setting in render that I don't understand?

Here's my .blend: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/32269

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try switching to GLSL shading in *3D view > Properties region (<kbd>N</kbd>) > Shading*:

[image]

Then it works as expected:

[image]