# Removing color and leaving the texture

Tags: texturing, game-engine, color

So basically was making a tree For **Game** (Using Blender game engine) then I got to some point where I have no clue how to work around with (Probably something simple).

Here's an image of the problem I think it'll be quite obvious lol.
[image]

So basically, I want the white off and the leaves texture to stay. I tried so many things but nothing has come out of it.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Related [https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18042/textured-alpha-not-showing-in-the-game-engine](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18042/textured-alpha-not-showing-in-the-game-engine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your image has an alpha channel then go to the Transparency section, bring down the Alpha value level to 0

[image]